# My basil is wilting

Tags: basil

Suddenly, my basil started wilting. I watered it and also placed in a bright spot but it didn’t improve. I harvested it a little bit but not much. Is the pot too small? I cannot think of any other reason. [image: here is the wilted herb!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is from the supermarket and sold as fresh herbs, it has probably been sprayed with a chemical to cause it to die after a certain time.  I have tried to grow rosemary several times from these and they die every single time without sprouting a single new leaf

Comment: oh wow! Now it all makes sense because I have bought it from a grocery store. This was my third time getting herbs from a supermarket. Should I buy it from a garden center then? Any suggestions?Interestingly, I bought a mint plant from home depot garden center and it's doing good. I have harvested it a couple of times already.

Comment: Farmers markets are best, having said that I once bought rosemary from my local market and the same thing happened.  I am 0-4 when it comes to rosemary 